# Datatables filtering

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am having difficulties using the filtering function of Datatables. I use version 1.10. This is what I tried:

```
$("#hide").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
       function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
          return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).attr('data-user') == 5;
       }
    );
    table.draw();
});    
$("#reset").click(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    table.draw();
});
```

But the table doesn't update. Is there something I may be doing wrong? The array in question appears to be getting updated when i do a console.log, but there is no sign of the function being called.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Filtering the Datatable. 
Loop through all the rows in Data table

```
$("#Datatable").html().find("xxx").hide();
or 
$('#Datatable tr').each(function(index,value) {
if( $(this).find('xxx'))
   {
      $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Give more details regrading the functionality.

Comment: This is what I am doing currently, but the pagination is not updated after hide